# Asp .net core datetime display format

Tags: asp.net, .net

I during code writing I encountered problem with DateTime: year consists of 6 digits.
Can someone tell me what is the reason of this fact?

```
  [Required]
  [DisplayName("Date of birth")]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  [CustomDateAttribute(ErrorMessage ="Incorrect date range")]     
  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

[image]
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GNSq.png)

Comment: Where are you trying to set date time which makes error??

Comment: In registration form

Comment: I meant to share your code

Comment: Without customdateattribute is same situation.

Comment: Photo added. check this out